# jQuery: Count children, display as string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to do something that I believe is fairly simple. On page load I would like to count all of the children of a `ul` and then display that number as a string. Here is the code I have so far:

**jQuery**

```
$('ul').load(function() {
    var txt = "1" + "/" + $("> *", this).length;
    $(".counter").html( txt );
});
```

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><img alt="Photo" src="images/photo.png" /></li>
    <li><img alt="Photo" src="images/photo.png" /></li>
    <li><img alt="Photo" src="images/photo.png" /></li>
</ul>

<p class="counter"></p>
```

So in this example, once the page loads, `p.counter` would contain the string "1/3". Not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: `$(ul)` should be `$('ul')` and the `load` event is not triggered for list elements. Just make the computation in the `ready` event handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you count the items on document ready?

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    var txt = "1"+ "/" + $("ul li").length;
    $(".counter").html( txt );
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/But8C/

Comment: Of course... I don't know why I didn't think of that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

first, I assume you mean a specific unique ul.  You'll probably want to give it an id, in that case, to avoid conflicts in case other uls appear on the page (listed below as "ulid").  You might wish to do the same with the counter as well, but if you can be sure you're not using that class elsewhere, you should be fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var txt = "1/" + $("#ulid").children().length()
    $("p.counter").html( txt );
}
```

Comment: In my case, it will be the only `ul` on the page so I can get away without using a class.